# Intellisense doesn't allow adding multiple css classes in class attribute of an element

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 RC Ultimate on my Windows 7 x64 bit system.

I have several CSS classes in a CSS file and have referenced it properly. Now see how I am doing

I added a class in my a `div` element like

```
<div class="page">
```

when I put my cursor after `page` and before `">`. And I press Space button, intellisense opens but it contains only item that I have already included, it is `page`.

I have to write all the other classes names completely by typing.
Please tell me if you are facing the same issue. If not, then someone please tell me how can I fix this.

#### Added Later

[Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760316/intellinsense-do-not-work-for-adding-multiple-css-classes), I have reported this [BUG](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760316/intellinsense-do-not-work-for-adding-multiple-css-classes) in Microsoft Connect.
I have just installed VS 2012 Update 2 and was hoping to get this fixed and **It is now fixed. No such issue anymore.** Thanks to Microsoft for considering my Bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760316/intellinsense-do-not-work-for-adding-multiple-css-classes) is now fixed with [Visual Studio 2012 Update 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912)

Answer (score 1):

It's a know issue with VS2012. Microsoft is aware of it and working on a fix ([BUG 760316: Intellinsense does not work for adding multiple classes](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760316/intellinsense-do-not-work-for-adding-multiple-css-classes))

You can still add multiple classes, you just have to type them out.

Comment: I had reported it.. And was hoping a to be fix in Update 1. But It is still not fixed. Waiting for next update.. :-(

Comment: fixed in VS 2012 Update 2. Thanks to Microsoft :-)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of typing spacebar alone, type Ctrl+Spacebar. it will show you all classes.

when you type only spacebar then it will show you classes starting with page. 
Do following.
go to css file. copy .page class and paste immidiately below and rename it as page1.
go back to your repro steps and you will 2 classes in intellisense now. One "page" and another "page1".

Comment: I know it.. intellisense show no class but a single class that is already included.. DO U HAVE vs12 installed..?

Comment: I verified this on VS12 RTM version. It will be great if you can post snapshot of the problem.

Comment: u better [go here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760316/intellinsense-do-not-work-for-adding-multiple-css-classes)